# GTX 1080 Not Using 100% Utilisation @ 1080p

Tags: graphics-card, performance, gaming, 1080p

I recently bought a GTX 1080 AG 8GB, It's boost clock is 2017 MHz. However, when I try to run games the GPU sits at 30-45% usage, despite the frame rate significantly varying form 20-80 FPS in the two games I've tested it with: Rust & Planet Coaster.

I've done A LOT of reading on the subject, and noticed it seems to be a common issue with no clear resolution. So I'll try and consolidate all the suspected issues into this post, with the hope that this can be resolved in a manner that others can follow.

Basically the issue is the GPU isn't cranking up to provide a steady frame rate, it's simply sitting at 30% the majority of the time. I've never seen it go above 60% usage in games at all. Benchmarks however do push the card, it seems to be only games that the GPU isn't pushing itself for. My understanding is the GPU should go to 70-100% to provide as many frames as it can, unless V-Sync is enabled. So why is my 1080 not pushing itself to provide more FPS? I understand that the card is intended for 4K, I purchased it to future proof, but it doesn't make sense that it's not pushing itself to run at 1080p... I've checked the following commonly suggested troubleshooting tasks:

**1) Suspected CPU Bottleneck**

This is very unlikely. I have an I7 3770K overclocked to 3.9 GHz, and I actively monitored the individual CPU Cores utilisation ~ they're never used more than 50-60% per core. Temperatures are also never above 60°

**2) Enabling Performance Mode & DSR (4K) in Nvidia Control Panel**

I've enabled Prefer Maximum Performance in the control panel, as well as Dynamic Screen Resolution (DSR) to try and run the games in 4K on my 1080p screen, to try and get the card to run at a higher FPS/use more power. This made no difference.

**3) Remove Drivers & Re-Install**

I've used DDU to remove all display drivers (including integrated) from my system in safe mode, and then re-installed the latest driver 382.53 - WHQL.

**4) Check for Windows Updates**

No windows updates available or pending.

**5) Setting FPS Target in ASUS GPU Tweak II**

I tried setting the FPS target to 250 FPS, this made no difference.

**System Details:**

- Windows 10 Pro x64
- CPU: I7 3770K @ 3.9 GHz
- Motherboard: ASUS MAXIMUS V GENE
- GPU: Asus GTX 1080 AG 8GB | 382.53 - WHQL

System Log: [Click Here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuvtZs4MIyQGmaNOeD1QB9N4NJY9SQ)
(Please use 2nd bottom log, dated 17-06-2017 02-25-50)

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: 20017 MHz would be 20 GHz which makes sense.

Comment: Corrected my typo, sorry.

Comment: GPU "Usage" would take into account the various parts of the GPU processing pipeline, if you are bottlenecking at any stage then the rest of the pipeline will stall and so you won't get 100% used.  It depends a lot on whether the game is highly memory intensive or compute intensive. Which side you fall on will depends on how many shader programs are running, whether you are using antialiasing, texture size and so on. It is probably nearly impossible to get a perfect 100% utilisation.

Comment: If you want to see close to 100% usage then the render test in [GPU-z](https://www.techpowerup.com/download/techpowerup-gpu-z/) is a good way to fully exercise a graphics card.  You can get to the render test by clicking the "?" next to the Bus Interface (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqheG.png) which will pop up a render test window.  When I click "Start Render Test" my card goes up to 93-95% GPU load.

Comment: Is your gpu usage bouncing up and down? Also what is your ram? Can you run a system benchmark and share the link at cpu.userbenchmark.com/Software Also in what games are you experiencing this?